# ssl handshake notification in Netty server

Tags: netty

In Netty, is there any way to receive notification that a ssl handshake completed successfully on the server side? I know that you can in the client by adding a listener when you call handshake(), but this only works on the client (since only the client should initiate the original handshake).

This seems like functionality the SslHandler should provide.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way atm. Would you mind open a feature request and I will see what I can do to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new here so I can't leave this as a comment rather than an answer.  Not to sure if this will help the answer any quicker but the community here mite be a bit more active on this topic.  I was unaware of this site until a few weeks back, you mite not be either.

https://serverfault.com/

Feel free to edit / remove this.

Answer (score 0):

In Netty 4, you can add a listener to handshakeFuture for handshake results:

```
sslHandler.handshakeFuture().addListener(f -> {
    if (f.isSuccess()) {
        // TODO:
    } else {
        // TODO:
    }
});
```